# Get JavaScript var value from a web page

Tags: javascript, php, json, xpath, web

In a php program, I have a web page in $page variable.

```
...
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.autostrade.it/autostrade-gis/gis.do", false, $context);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
...
```

In this page there are some javascript and I want to take the json data contained in the variable called "evtsVar".

```
...
<script ...>
    ...
</script>
<script ...>
    ...
    var evtsVar = {json data}
    ...
</script>
```

Use Xpath query is the right method? How can I do to take this variable value?

Thank you all and sorry for my English.

Comment: are you trying to access jsondata from javascript to php script?

Comment: No. How i can access ti json data?

Comment: yes you want to play with the json data right.. if you want to play with it in php side you need ajax  if you want to access it in client side you can do that without any issues.

Comment: If it's content is rendered in client-side, you can't take its value in server load

Comment: If you have viewed the source of the page he has provided, you can see the javascript variable "evtsVar". I thought he wants to get that parameter as JSON object and provided the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very specific question about a certain page. I've analyzed the page you have provided the link. There is a variable within a script tag. You want to get that in JSON.

I've used jquery for the solution, strongly recommended for you too.

Get the page first:

```
<?

$page = file_get_contents("http://www.autostrade.it/autostrade-gis/gis.do", false, $context);

?>
```

Then get the page in a javascript variable:

```
var page = <?php echo json_encode( $page ) ?>;
```

Now we have the page, we should find the string starting with "var evtsVar = ", ending with ";":

```
var preString = "var evtsVar = ";
var postString = ";";
var preIndex = page.indexOf( preString );
var searchIndex = preIndex + page.substring( preIndex ).indexOf( postString );

var evtsString = page.slice( preIndex + preString.length , searchIndex );
```

Now get parse the string to a json object and print:

```
var evtsVar = JSON.parse( evtsString );

console.log( evtsVar );
```

Tested, works.

Comment: It is the same thing if I do a search in the variable $page in php with the search function on strings?

Comment: indexOf is like a search function. Was that a question? Have you tested above code within your platform?

Comment: Exactly, I search the string "var = evtsVar" in the variable $page with 'strpos' php function.
It appears equivalent to your method. Your code works.
I was wondering if there is a method such as those used to make the HTML elements with xpath query.